# If I am using AMP do I need to serve two sites or a responsive one will do the trick?

Tags: css, mobile, amp-html

I want to understand more the purpose and way of working with AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages).

If I am using AMP do I need to serve two sites or a responsive one will do the trick? or what is the correct work approach?

Answer (score 1):

**AMP can work with an existing website, RWD would replace a current website**

**AMP currently only works with static content, RWD can be used for any website**

AMP solves a very specific problem: delivering mobile-friendly published content as fast as possible. For websites delivering published content to mobile users, AMP will very likely provide a better user experience faster than anything else out there. However, AMP is not full-featured enough for websites that rely on web forms and custom JavaScript functionality.

Its really depend on your content and service.